# Unnecessary database transactions cause slowness?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions

I am working in a Spring, Java, Hibernate, Postgresql environment. I am seeing some pretty severe slowness on my database. My specific question is how bad is it if I am adding Spring's `@Transactional` annotation to a class that contains methods that do not hit the database? In other words, they do not require a transaction. Suppose these methods are some of the more frequently used methods.

So something like this (just an example):

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ProjectManager {

    public String getProjectUrl(Project project) {
         //simple logic that does not use the database
         return "/my/url/" + project.getId();
    }

}
```

I understand there are a lot of factors that can cause database slowness. I am just wondering if this is a huge red flag or not that big of a deal? Should I pull these methods out and put them into a different class that is not marked with `@Transactional`?

TIA

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks on this method with and without the `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: *"how bad is it if I am adding Spring's `@Transactional` annotation"* Very little, unless you profiled the code that it says you have a problem there, and I doubt it will.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it will be of any help, but [here](http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/) you can find an explanation of what is going on exactly when you use `@Transactional`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `getProjectUrl` method will be intercepted with spring aspect, that:

1. Creates transaction if required
2. Invokes your method
3. Completes transaction

This is well-described at [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained). Also, Spring is not smart enough to understand that method code doesn't use DB at all ([as we see see in source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.java#L267)).

So, we can definitely conclude that Spring's **`@Transactional` causes some overhead**.

But what kind of overhead?

- Java in any case - Aspect code implements anyway
- Depending on [`propagation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-propagation) value of `@Transactional` we may be forced to create physical (DB) transaction. This causes  network + connection + db-side overhead.

From other side, if you remove `@Transactional`, you should also know that **Postgres wraps ANY non-transactional SQL query in implicit transaction** ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-transactions.html)):

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it.

Finally, the answer: Do not use `@Transactional` if your method does't deal with DB.